# Splitting records and duplicating data into split records (odd table structure)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this (Don't ask. I didn't create it but I have to work with it). Let's call it OddTable...

```
Heading     Details           Issue1   Issue2   Issue3   Comments   BatchId
ItemID      SN1001                                                  10
Date Done   2018-12-18                                              10
Section1                        1         1        1                10
AreaA                           1         1                         10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
AreaB                                                               10
ItemID      SN1002                                                  11
ItemID      SN1003                                                  11
ItemID      SN1004                                                  11
Date Done   2018-12-11                                              11
Section1                                                  Test      11
AreaA                                     1               Stuff     11
AreaB                           1         1               Even More 11
ItemID      SN1005                                                  12
ItemID      SN1006                                                  12
Date Done   2018-12-11                                              12
Section1                                           1                12
AreaA                                     1        1      Blah      12
AreaB                           1                         Yada      12
```

Looking to select results that look like this (Separate each ItemID into it's own set of records duplicated from the batch):

```
Heading     Details           Issue1   Issue2   Issue3   Comments   
ItemID      SN1001                                                  
Date Done   2018-12-18                                              
Section1                        1         1        1                
AreaA                           1         1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
AreaB                                                               
ItemID      SN1002                                                  
Date Done   2018-12-11                                              
Section1                                                  Test      
AreaA                                     1               Stuff     
AreaB                           1         1               Even More 
ItemID      SN1003                                                  
Date Done   2018-12-11                                              
Section1                                                  Test      
AreaA                                     1               Stuff     
AreaB                           1         1               Even More 
ItemID      SN1004                                                  
Date Done   2018-12-11                                              
Section1                                                  Test      
AreaA                                     1               Stuff     
AreaB                           1         1               Even More 
ItemID      SN1005                                                  
Date Done   2018-12-11                                              
Section1                                           1                
AreaA                                     1        1      Blah      
AreaB                           1                         Yada
ItemID      SN1006                                                  
Date Done   2018-12-11                                              
Section1                                           1                
AreaA                                     1        1      Blah      
AreaB                           1                         Yada
```

NOTE: The BatchId column is not required in the result and is used only to distinguish the group where the data needs to be duplicated.

Thank you so very much for your help.

Comment: Please explain the logic that you are using to fill in the additional rows.

Comment: there are always just four last rows per batch (`date done, section1, areaA, areaB`)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry about that was just editing the question to include that. Essentially, I'm trying to split each ItemID into it's own set of records where the 'Date Done', 'Section1', 'AreaA' and  'AreaB' rows are duplicated from the same BatchId

Comment: @RadimBača Yes, the number of rows in a batch are set. It's just the number of ItemID rows that differ

Comment: If you could turn this data into something consumable this isn't all that difficult. I would be happy to show you but I am not going to spend a half hour putting this data into a table. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange thank you for that. Much appreaciated.

Comment: So does that mean you are going to post something usable? Or just an empty thanks...

Comment: @SeanLange wasn't meant to be empty. I'm sorry you took it that way. Will post an answer soon but was just suddenly swamped with work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had some time to think about it and came up with this solution (along the lines-ish of what was suggested by @Sean Lange). What I came up with was to split the same table up into 2 parts and then inner join them both so I'd get the repeated data. I'm sure someone will point out a more efficient way to do this but until then this is what I've got. Query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    Part1.ItemId
    ,Part1.DateDone
    ,Part2.Area
    ,Issue1
    ,Issue2
    ,Issue3
    ,Comments
    ,Part2.BatchId
FROM
(SELECT 
    *
FROM( 
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN Heading = 'ItemID' THEN Details END as ItemId
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN Heading = 'Date Done' THEN Details END) OVER (PARTITION BY BatchId) as DateDone
        ,BatchId
    FROM 
        dbo.OddTable
) as StartingData
WHERE ItemId not like 'NULL'
) as Part1
inner join
(SELECT
    Heading as Area
    ,Issue1
    ,Issue2
    ,Issue3
    ,Comment
    ,BatchId
FROM
    dbo.OddTable
WHERE Heading in ('Section1','AreaA','AreaB')
) as Part2
ON Part1.BatchId = Part2.BatchId

ORDER BY Part1.ItemId,Part1.BatchId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cross apply`

```
select t2.*
from table t1
cross apply (
  select 'ItemID' Heading, t1.Details, null Issue1, null Issue2, null Issue3, null Comments
  union all
  select *
  from table t3
  where t1.BatchId = t3.BathId and Heading in ('Date Done', 'Section1', 'AreaA', 'AreaB')
) t2
where t1.heading = 'ItemID'
```

However, the problem is that the result of the SELECT is not implicitly ordered. Therefore, you may obtain the result rows swapped somehow. Assigning some `ID` in order to ensure the requested order would require more effort.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Please forgive my newbieness but there is only 1 table.  Which table would t3 be?

Comment: `t3` is an alias for your table. Since I use your table more than once, the alias is needed to differentiate the tables.

Comment: My apologies again for the back and forth. So, which one is t1?